# Cypress fails on CI/CD on next js project

Tags: next.js, cypress

I am using Cypress for creating integration tests for my NextJs application. I have 2 scenarios and in both i use:

```js
cy.findByText('First text').should('exist')
```

```js
cy.findByText('Second text').should('exist')
```

Both situations pass when i run cypress locally. But when they run on github i got this:

     `AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find content: 'First text' within the selector: 'div' but never did.` 
 Why the tests pass locally and fail on github actions? How to solve this? Does somebody faced this issues?

My scenarios:

```js
Scenario: Edit edit success
Given I am logged in
  And I click on edit user
And I change a value
And I click on submit
Then I should see success

Scenario: Edit edit error
Given I am logged in
  And I click on edit user
And I add a bad value
And I click on submit
Then I should see error

// Cucumber


// 1
Given('I am logged in', () => {
  ...login code
});
When('I click on edit user', () => {
  ...click on edit tab
});
And('I change a value', () => {
  ...change value functionality
});
And('I click on submit', () => {
  cy.route('PUT', '/user/123', 'fixture:update');
  cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click();
});
Then('I should see success', () => {
  cy.contains('div', 'Success').should('exist');
});
// 2
Given('I am logged in', () => {
  ...login code
});
When('I click on edit user', () => {
  ...click on edit tab
});
And('I add a bad value', () => {
  ...change value functionality
});
And('I click on submit', () => {
  cy.route('PUT', '/user/123', 'fixture:update-bad-response');
  cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click();
});
Then('I should see error', () => {
  cy.contains('div', 'Success').should('exist');
});

// Cypress
```

Comment: Have you tried running from a clean install. Do you commit package-lock.json (you should) and are things like the node version identical?

Comment: @Evert, `Have you tried running from a clean install.` how to do that?

Comment: Create a fresh directory, do a a new clone from git and run `npm i`. This is just to ensure that there's not some weird uncommitted / dangling changes in your working directory

Comment: @Evert, working good with a fresh install

Comment: @Evert, what else could be the issue?

Comment: Are you starting your app locally during the pipeline execution or are you executing the tests on some kind of dev environment? If the latter, is it possible that your texts have not yet been deployed and therefore are not found?

Comment: If you have your screenshot and video enabled, what are those showing you?

Comment: @jjhelguero, i added my scenarious. Could you help? All works locally but when i build and run `cypress: run` appears that error that i mentioned above.

Comment: @SebastianoVierk, i added my scenarious. Could you help? All works loccaly but when i build and run `cypress: run` appears that error that i mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

the speed in CI (github actions) is different compare to your local machine, due to Memory and CPU

as solution add default timeout to your `cypress.json` file something like 20sec

- `"defaultCommandTimeout": 20000,`

Comment: so the speed in CI is higher or lower than on local env?

Comment: does your problem solved?

Comment: No, could you help?

Comment: yes, sure can you share your code somewhere?

Comment: when i build loccalluy and run `cypress:run` i got the same error message.

Comment: I added my code in the question. Could you help please? My code is similar with what i added. How to change my code?

Comment: can you please try to modify
```Then('I should see success', () => {
  cy.get('button[type="submit"]').should('not.exist');
  cy.contains('div', 'Success').should('exist');
});``` to make sure that prev action is finished

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243760/discussion-between-asking-and-zhenek).

Comment: could you access the chat please?

Comment: I tested and i don't have any other elements on the page that could contain the same message. Also, i suppose that the second request does not occur. Instead of bad message according the second scenario, i got a message like `Access denied`. I tested this and it appears only if the request does not occur. Why the second request does not occur but first pass?